# Date conversions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to convert MM/DD/YY (for example: 12/23/14) to YYYY-MM-DD (for example: 2014-12-23) in MS SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Is `12/23/14` a string/varchar?

Comment: yes or you may consider it as a date also

Comment: Cast ('12/23/14' as date) as [MyDateCol]  ?? (Swap the fixed date here for your string/variable column name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),126)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to load the data into a column that is the Date datatype, then you can cast a string as a date:

CAST('12/23/14' AS DATE)